# How to get array values from a JSON file in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I need to write a foreach using these user's ids:

The array that the API returns:

```
{"users":[{"id":"14"},{"id":"19"}]}
```

I want to send a mail based on each user id, thats why I need a foreach statement. How do I do that?

Comment: Please at least give it a go and show us your attempt. `json_decode` and `foreach` will help you here.

Comment: I'm using Pusher's api for websockets. And the returning value of a channel's connection is: $response[ 'body' ] = {"users":[{"id":"14"},{"id":"19"}]}

i don't have experience getting array's values on a foreach

Comment: Then read the manual on foreach and if you get stuck come back again

Comment: Already did, i just need to get those user's ids, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, here we could first `json_decode`, then loop through the `users` and append a `username` maybe using `id` values to the array:

```
$str = '{"users":[{"id":"14"},{"id":"19"}]}';

$array = json_decode($str, true);
foreach ($array["users"] as $key => $value) {
    $array["users"][$key]["username"] = "user_" . $value["id"];
}

var_dump($array);
```

#### Output

```
array(1) {
  ["users"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "14"
      ["username"]=>
      string(7) "user_14"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "19"
      ["username"]=>
      string(7) "user_19"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! i did this:
   $str = '{"users":[{"id":"14"},{"id":"19"}]}';

   $array = json_decode($str, true);
   foreach ($array["users"] as $key => $value) {

       echo $value['id'];
      }

And the output was the user's ids, it worked